# Type geometry does not exist after CREATE EXTENSION postgis

Tags: python, django, postgresql, postgis, django-oscar

After creating new postgres db and loading necessary postgis extension

```
$ createdb  demodb
$ psql demodb
> CREATE EXTENSION postgis;
> CREATE EXTENSION postgis_topology;
```

I get `django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: type "geometry" does not exist` exception thrown while running django `manage.py migrate`

After this I tried running the failed query in pgadmin and it said the same: `type "geometry" does not exist`

Although appending `CREATE EXTENSION postgis;` before the query seems to fix this and query returned ok. But running `manage.py migrate` again throwed the same exception.

Isn't loading new extension permanent? And if so, how can I load it permanently, so it is loaded when running `migrate`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CREATE EXTENSION` is *permanent* for the database you are running it in. It creates objects in a given (or the current default) schema. [Per documentation:](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createextension.html)

> ***schema_name***
>
> The name of the schema in which to install the extension's objects, given that the extension allows its contents to be relocated.
>   The named schema must already exist. If not specified, and the
>   extension's control file does not specify a schema either, the current
>   default object creation schema is used.
>
> Remember that the extension itself is not considered to be within any schema: extensions have unqualified names that must be unique
>   database-wide. But objects belonging to the extension can be within
>   schemas.

Check which schemas are involved in `psql`:

```
\connect mydb
\x 
\dx postgis*
```

The schemas used must be in your current [`search_path`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9067335/how-to-create-table-inside-specific-schema-by-default-in-postgres/9067777#9067777) (or you'd have to schema-qualify all references).
I am not sure `migrate` includes additional schemas or extensions at all.
Most probably, this is an issue with the `search_path`

Answer (score 0):

I needed to give my database user permission to access the postgis schema. I ran the following while connected to my django database and then migrate was able to run successfully.

`GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON SCHEMA postgis TO username;`

Answer (score 0):

For me `grant usage on schema <postgis-install-schema> to <myschema>` solved it (`<postgis-install-schema>` was `public` in my case).

(`grant all privileges` as suggested from *TechnoConserve* may be too much for security reasons)